# Delphi cxDBPivotGrid - цикл по итоговой колонке

Tags: devexpress, delphi

Вот снимок

[image: cxDBPivotGrid]

Подскажите, как пройтись циклом по всем строкам указанной колонки.

Вернее вопрос по связке cxDBPivotGrid + cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet.
Требуется циклом программно пройтись по итогам cxDBPivotGrid, при этом внутри цикла требуется пробегаться по записям привязанного cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet`а и обрабатывать данные этого самого cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet`а тоже в цикле.

Т.е. в цикле нужно выделять записи cxDBPivotGrid`а, чтобы cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet генерировал набор своих записей?
или есть более простые способы?

С чего начать?

Сейчас пока пытаюсь врубиться в правку, основные понятия и т.д. С TcxDBPivotGrid + cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet не работал до этого момента.
В принципе, к cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet привязан cxGrid, а по cxGrid`у я уже смогу "пробежаться".

Answer (score 1):

Начало есть:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  s: string;
begin
  cxDBPivotGrid1.BeginUpdate;
  try
    for I := 0 to Pred(cxDBPivotGrid1.ViewData.RowCount) do
    begin
        if s = '' then
          s := cxDBPivotGrid1.ViewData.CellsAsText[i, 0]
        else
          s := s + sLineBreak + cxDBPivotGrid1.ViewData.CellsAsText[i, 0];
    end;
     ShowMessage(s);
  finally
    cxDBPivotGrid1.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

Теперь второй вопрос.
К cxDBPivotGrid привязаны cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet + cxGrid и ниже отображаются данные в сетке.
Как сделать второй (внутренний) цикл по cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet для каждой строки PivotGrid`а?

Для наглядности такой пример:
[image: картинко]

1. Переходим на строку в cxDBPivotGrid
2. Обрабатываем все записи из cxPivotGridDrillDownDataSet

Что-то типа master-detail получается.